# Windows-XP VM fails to boot after import in VirtualBox-4.x

Tags: windows-xp, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a perfectly fine Windows-XP virtual machine in VirtualBox (v4.2.22) on my laptop with a 64-bit host OS, which works fine. I used the "Export" utility of VirtualBox to create an "OVA" file of my VM to transfer it to another computer.

The other computer also has VirtualBox (v4.3.x) but with a 32-bit host OS, and I successfully imported the Windows-XP OVA. Unfortunately the Windows-XP VM fails to boot! It fails at the "Welcome" splash-screen and automatically restarts. It just keeps on restarting every-time at the "Welcome" splash.

Pressing F8 at boot, I can open the Advanced Options menu, where I can boot into "Safe Mode". The VM does boot successfully with "Safe Mode", but I don't know what to do to find out the cause and fix it.

In the Advanced Options menu and have also used the "Disable automatic restart on system failure", which stops restarting after the boot fails at the "Welcome" splash, but no error messages are shown on the screen and the system is just hung on the "Welcome" screen!

Can anyone help me find the cause and fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Drivers, Drivers, Drivers.
These steps will usually work in Safe Mode on the new host machine, but If possible, go back to your original machine on the original host system, uninstall Vbox additions, and then do the following:

> These steps are to be performed within each Guest OS. Do not perform
>   these on the HOST

.

Use the following instructions to open the Device manager WITH the option of viewing non-connected devices:

- Open cmd prompt as administrator and run the following;

> set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1
>
> Start devmgmt.msc

in Device Manager:

Click View menu -> Show hidden devices

Start expanding ALL nodes and uninstall any devices that are greyed out (faded icons).  You will notice most are named msft virtual or similar.
Tip:  The delete button will also uninstall.  So you can simply click and delete, click – delete and so on.

NOW export your Vbox VM and re-import it, you should be just fine.

Comment: Can't I do this work only on the target guest, instead of doing it on the first and then exporting and so on ... ?

Comment: I did run these commands on the target OS in "Safe Mode", but there were no greyed/faded devices! What can I do in "Safe Mode" to find out what caused the problem in the last "Normal" boot that failed?

Comment: The reason to go back to the source and clean it up from there is that  it will likely resolve your boot issue.  Different versions of virtualbox implemented slightly different hardware abstraction layers (HAL) in regard to USB controllers.  Try uninstalling (in safe mode) all of the USB related devices in the guest os.  Shutdown and then disable USB in virtualbox settings and reboot.  Migrating between virtualbox versions with different host hardware usually causes this kind of pain.

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't boot. I uninstalled all USB devices in Device Manager, shut down the system and disabled USB support in VirtualBox, then started the VM but it still doesn't boot. I think we are not on the right path. What can I do in "Safe Mode" to find out what caused the problem in the last "Normal" boot that failed? Are there any system-logs in Windows-XP that tells what caused the problem?